# Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat ignores Method Roles

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

i use Spring Boot 1.2.1 with embedded Tomcat and Spring Boot Starter Security. Furthermore I use a RestController for some webservices and I want that only certain users with certain roles can access the webservices. But it does not work, the security does not use the RoleVoter to check the roles. With the following example the user "user" can access the webservices although he hasnt the right roles!

First my application configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ImportResource( "classpath:net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml" )
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource( "classpath:application.properties" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true )
public class ItemConfiguration { ... }
```

Now my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser( "user" ).password( "password" ).roles( "USER" );
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.httpBasic();
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

The Restcontroller

```
@RestController
public class QueryController {

  @Secured( { "ROLE_ADMIN" } )
  @RequestMapping( value = "/", method = { POST }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
  ResponseEntity< List< BaseEntity > > query( @RequestBody @Valid final ItemQueryRequestData request )
      throws Exception {
      return new ResponseEntity<>( "", HttpStatus.OK );
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database = item
spring.data.mongodb.host = ${MONGODB_URI:pimpoc01}
spring.data.mongodb.port = ${MONGODB_PORT:27017}

spring.activemq.broker-url=${BROKER_URL:tcp://pimpoc01:61616}
spring.activemq.user=
spring.activemq.password=
spring.activemq.pooled=true

queue.item.in.channelId = item-in
queue.item.in.concurrentConsumers = 1
queue.item.in.destination = item-in

queue.itemOption.in.channelId = itemOption-in
queue.itemOption.in.concurrentConsumers = 1
queue.itemOption.in.destination = itemOption-in

queue.style.in.channelId = style-in
queue.style.in.concurrentConsumers = 1
queue.style.in.destination = style-in

queue.concurrentConsumers = 50
queue.dataCreation.response = dataCreationResponse

queue.structureAttributeValue.in.channelId = structureAttributeValue-in
queue.structureAttributeValue.in.concurrentConsumers = 1
queue.structureAttributeValue.in.destination = structureAttributeValue-in

validation.endpoint = ${VALIDATOR_URI:http://pimpoc01:8080/validator}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the content of your application.properties? Maybe you have a property, which interferes here.

Comment: @mathias-noack Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line from security configuration. I think `@Order` annotation is overriding the basic authentication.

```
@Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
```

Comment: I removed it but nothing changed. For the decision if an user can access the webservice it calls only the `WebExpressionVoter` instead of a `RoleVoter`! Only the `RoleVoter` checks the roles of an user.

Comment: In this documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html , if you go to the end of the page. It says if Actuator is in use, **the default user will have the ADMIN role as well as the USER role.**. I din't understand this statement completely, but not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: Yes, I read this already, but i dont use the Actuator. As you can see above I dont use the standard user either. I only have one user with the role "USER" but still he can access the webservices.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and solved by making my controller methods public, i.e. make `QueryController.query` method `public`.